# OpenCV image conversion from RGB to Grayscale using imread giving poor results

Tags: opencv

I'm loading a 24 Bit RGB image from a PNG file into my OpenCV application.

However loading the image as grayscale directly using `imread` gives a very poor result.

```
Mat src1 = imread(inputImageFilename1.c_str(), 0);
```

Loading the RGB image as RGB and converting it to Grayscale gives a much better looking result.

```
Mat src1 = imread(inputImageFilename1.c_str(), 1);
cvtColor(src1, src1Gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

I'm wondering if I'm using `imread` for my image type correctly. Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

The image converted to grayscale using `imread` is shown here:
[image: Bad result]

The image converted to grayscale using `cvtColor` is shown here:
[image: Good result]

Comment: "Color" image in OpenCV means BGR. So second version of your code is not correct. It should use `CV_BGR2GRAY` for color conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried converting the image to grayscale using CV_BGR2GRAY instead of CV_RGB2GRAY, but got the same result.

Comment: Could you also attach your original image?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post images to my posts with my current reputation. Also there is a limit to 2 hyperlinks within posts with my reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. the original image is located here: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/F8iLVPIuFR5LiZJVe9sAqmfnfsOOxMA_38d73O1A0AM?feat=directlink

Comment: I've tried your image and both versions of code produce good-looking images. What version of OpenCV are you using? What OS? What version of `libpng` have you installed (if you are working on Unix/Mac)?

Comment: My configuration:
OpenCV 2.3.1
Ubuntu 11.04 x64
libpng: 1.2.44 (checked with libpng-config --version)

Comment: The image in my previous comment might have gotten converted during upload. I've uploaded a version which I checked did not get converted (and shows the bad image quality using code line 1 above). Here is the link: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/741vgSMlGfsUklVst5H4s2fnfsOOxMA_38d73O1A0AM?feat=email

Comment: I've tried your version of `libpng` and two versions of input image, but both ways of conversion work for me.

Comment: Not sure how to debug this any further...

Comment: Is there any particular reason for which the png image, being grayscale, cannot be saved as grayscale png image?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was having the same issue today. Ultimately, I compared three methods:

```
//method 1
cv::Mat gs = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

//method 2
cv::Mat color = cv::imread(filename, 1); //loads color if it is available
cv::Mat gs_rgb(color.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::cvtColor(color, gs_rgb, CV_RGB2GRAY);

//method 3
cv::Mat gs_bgr(color.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::cvtColor(color, gs_bgr, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Methods 1 (loading grayscale) and 3 (CV_BGR2GRAY) produce identical results, while method 2 produces a different result. For my own ends, I've started using CV_BGR2GRAY.

My input files are jpgs, so there might be issues related to your particular image format.

Comment: Opencv imread returns image in BGR format , so I think the correct conversion to GRAY Scale is CV_BGR2GRAY as you have mentioned in the 3rd method

Answer (score 10):

The simple answer is, that openCV functions uses the BGR format. If you read in a image with `imread` or `VideoCapture`, it'll be always BGR. If you use RGB2GRAY, you interchange the blue channel with the green. The formula to get the brightness is

```
y = 0.587*green + 0.299*red + 0.114*blue
```

so if you change green and blue, this will cause an huge calculation error.

Greets

Comment: Isn't it then also interchanging the red channel? In this case interpreting the given `BGR` as `RGB` which then leads to (the actual) `B` being falsely interpreted as `R`, and `R` as `B`?

So according to your answer the fix would be replacing `CV_RGB2GRAY ` in the `cvtColor` call with `CV_BGR2GRAY`?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem once, working with OpenGL shaders. It seems that the first container that OpenCV reads your image with does not support all the ranges of color and hence you see that the image is a poor grayscale transformation. However once you convert the original image into grayscale using cvtColor the container is different from the first one and supports all ranges. In my opinion the first one uses less than 8 bits for grayscale or changing to the grayscale uses a bad method. But the second one gives smooth image because of more bits in gray channel.

Comment: Did you find a documentation to support this reasoning? Facing a similar issue & I'm inclined to believe this might be the case but cannot find anything conclusive to put down in my reasoning

Comment: Well it is the case since the frame buffer contains a range of 255 for each color and also 255 for monochrome spectrum. You need floating points to support a better range.