# Opencv - Grayscale mode Vs gray color conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am working in opencv(2.4.11) python(2.7) and was playing around with gray images. I found an unusual behavior when loading image in gray scale mode and converting image from BGR to GRAY. Following is my experimental code:

```
import cv2

path = 'some/path/to/color/image.jpg'

# Load color image (BGR) and convert to gray
img = cv2.imread(path)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Load in grayscale mode
img_gray_mode = cv2.imread(path, 0)

# diff = img_gray_mode - img_gray
diff = cv2.bitwise_xor(img_gray,img_gray_mode)

cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
cv2.waitKey()
```

When I viewed the difference image, I can see the left out pixels instead of jet black image. Can you suggest any reason? What is the correct way of working with gray images.
*P.S. When I use both the images in SIFT, keypoints are different which may lead to different outcome specially when working with bad quality images.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV image conversion from RGB to Grayscale using imread giving poor results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461075/opencv-image-conversion-from-rgb-to-grayscale-using-imread-giving-poor-results)

Comment: **Please note that this is not a duplicate**, because the OP is aware that the image from `cv2.imread` is in BGR format (unlike the suggested duplicate question that assumed it was RGB hence the provided answers only address that issue

Answer (score 84, accepted):

<sub>**Note: This is not a duplicate**, because the OP is aware that the image from `cv2.imread` is in BGR format (unlike the suggested duplicate question that assumed it was RGB hence the provided answers only address that issue)</sub>

To illustrate, I've opened up this same color JPEG image:

[image]

once using the conversion

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

and another by loading it in gray scale mode

```
img_gray_mode = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Like you've documented, the diff between the two images is not perfectly 0, I can see diff pixels in towards the left and the bottom

[image]

I've summed up the diff too to see

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(diff)
# I got 6143, on a 494 x 750 image
```

**I tried all `cv2.imread()` modes**

Among all the `IMREAD_` modes for `cv2.imread()`, only `IMREAD_COLOR` and `IMREAD_ANYCOLOR` can be converted using `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, and both of them gave me the same diff against the image opened in `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`

The difference doesn't seem that big. My guess is comes from the differences in the numeric calculations in the two methods (loading grayscale vs conversion to grayscale)

Naturally what you want to avoid is fine tuning your code on a particular version of the image just to find out it was suboptimal for images coming from a different source.

**In brief, let's not mix the versions and types in the processing pipeline.**

So I'd keep the image sources homogenous, e.g. if you have capturing the image from a video camera in BGR, then I'd use BGR as the source, and do the BGR to grayscale conversion `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Vice versa if my ultimate source is grayscale then I'd open the files and the video capture in gray scale `cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

Comment: The reason is that there are multiple implementations of the grayscale conversion in play.  `cvtColor`() is THE opencv implementation and will be consistent across platforms. When you use `imread`() to convert to grayscale, you are at the mercy of the platform-specific implementation of `imread`().  I wouldn't be surprised if `imread`() returns slightly different grayscale values on each platform.  

I can't think of any reason to ever convert to grayscale in `imread`.

Comment: What @MichaelGallacher said. The coefficients used by `cvtColor` are here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp#L22