# Greyscale Image python Implementation

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I try to convert a RGB image to grayscale using python as a function but the problem is I give it a RGB image that have height, width and channel but after the code I should have an image with just height and width but it gives me an image with height, width and channel why?

```
def RGBtoGRAY(img):
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    grayimg = img
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            grayimg[i,j] = 0.3 * image[i,j][0] + 0.59 * image[i,j][1] +  0.11 * image[i,j][2]
    return grayimg
```

the size of the input image is

```
image.shape 
(533, 541, 3)
```

the size of the output image is

```
grayimage.shape 
(533, 541, 3)
```

normally I want to find in the size of the output image

```
(533, 541)
```

Comment: `grayimg = img` isn't creating a new image. It just takes the reference of the input. You want to create a new image with the same dimensions.

Comment: Does e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203970/opencv-grayscale-mode-vs-gray-color-conversion help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a for loop, because you intent to solve it "manually" (like C code), there are number of issues with your implementation:

- The assignment `grayimg = img` in Python does not create a copy of `img` (the result is that `grayimg` referencing `img`).
  You meant to use: `grayimg = img.copy()`.
- `img` has **3** dimensions, so when using `grayimg = img`, `grayimg` also has 3 dimensions.
  You need to create `grayimg` with two dimensions.
  Example for creating `grayimg` and initialize to zeros:

  ```
  grayimg = np.zeros((height, width), img.dtype)
  ```
- Inside the for loop, you are using `image` instead of `img`.

Here is a corrected version of `RGBtoGRAY`:

```
def RGBtoGRAY(img):
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    #grayimg = img
    # Create height x width array with same type of img, and initialize with zeros.
    grayimg = np.zeros((height, width), img.dtype)
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            grayimg[i,j] = 0.3 * img[i,j][0] + 0.59 * img[i,j][1] +  0.11 * img[i,j][2]
    return grayimg
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using `for` loops when performing image processing since it is very slow. Instead you can use Numpy which is highly optimized for vector operations. Using [this grayscale conversion formula](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert):

```
gray = R * .299 + G * .587 + B * .114
```

**Method #1:** [`apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def grayscale(colors):
    r, g, b = colors
    return 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b

# Create image of size 100x100 of random pixels
# Convert to grayscale
image = np.random.randint(255, size=(100,100,3),dtype=np.uint8)
gray = np.apply_along_axis(grayscale, 2, image)

# Display
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Before `->` After

[image]
[image]

**Method #2:** [`cv2.cvtColor`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)

You could use OpenCV directly and read in the image as grayscale with [`cv2.imread`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image) by passing in the `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` or `0` flag to load the image as grayscale.

```
image = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # OR
# image = cv2.imread('img.png', 0)
```

If you already have the image loaded, you can convert the RGB or BGR image to grayscale using [`cv2.cvtColor`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)

```
image = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```