# Moviepy : How to read greyscale movies frame by frame?

Tags: python, computer-vision, moviepy

Disclaimer : I have no experience in computer vision or image processing, but I need to process videos to obtain data for machine learning.

I wish to read a greyscale movie (I made it using greyscale images) - frame by frame using moviepy. For further processing, I need greyscale frames. Here is my code:

```
clip = VideoFileClip('movie.mp4') 
count =1
for frames in clip.iter_frames():
    print frames.shape
    count+=1
print count
```

The frame shapes come out to be (360L, 480L, 3L) while I was expecting (360L, 480L). And this puzzles me. Is there a way to get the "expected" shape? Python OpenCV ideas may work too, but I would prefer moviepy.

Comment: Is that just returning you the pixel array? i.e. you have 360 height, 480 width and 3 channels (probably RGB)

Comment: @EdChum : Yes, it is returning RGB frames. But I want greyscale frames

Comment: I don't know about moviepy, but you could convert RGB to HSL and take only the "L" component (luminosity), with something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html . If your frame is in a numpy array, you could also use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278323/converting-image-from-rgb-to-hsv-color-space. Finally, if the images are already greyscale, maybe the same value lies in the 3 channels. In this case, you could simply take the first channel and ignore the others (check what values the data actually contains).

Comment: you want to use `cvtColor` see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461075/opencv-image-conversion-from-rgb-to-grayscale-using-imread-giving-poor-results

Comment: If there isn't nothing in moviepy to do so, you can multiply the 3 color channels with appropriate values, something like: `gray = 0.2126* frame[:,:,0] + 0.7152*frame[:,:,1] + 0.0722*frame[:,:,2]`. In this way you can avoid to use another library just for this task

Comment: @jjmontes All channels are not the same. I did l0= frames[:,:,0]
l1= frames[:,:,1], and sum(sum(l0-l1)) yields 62059

Comment: I recommend floyd-steinberg dithering to get gray from color.

Answer (score 1):

If your are dealing with videos and images, OpenCV is your friend:

```
import cv2
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip('movie.mp4') 
count =1
for frames in clip.iter_frames():
    gray_frames = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    print frames.shape
    print gray_frames.shape
    count+=1
print count
```